# What is the general form for "how [adverb] do you [verb]?" in Spanish?

Tags: adverbios, preguntas

When I put *how quickly will you walk?* into Google Translate (maybe not the ideal source but that's my starting point), it gives me:

> ¿Con qué rapidez vas a caminar?

Based on this and other examples from Google Translate, I see the pattern that in Spanish, a "how" question using an adverb takes the form:

> ¿Con qué [noun form of quality described by adverb] [verb]?

Intuitively, though, I would think that the template would be:

> ¿Cómo [adverb] [verb]?

Which is more natural?  I found no Google hits for either *Con qué rapidez vas a caminar* or *Cómo rapidamente caminas*.

Comment: If this isn't a duplicate, it's a near duplicate. There are three possible structures: *¿cuán [adj]...? / ¿qué tan [adj]...? / ¿cómo de [adj]...?* The first is universal, but can be of a rather high register. More commonly​ you'll hear the latter two, but they are strongly differentiated by region (such that in some, the other could potentially even sound wrong).

Comment: You'll use the unmarked form of the adjective. So *¿cuán rápido vas a caminar?* for example

Comment: @guifa I don't know if I understand correctly. When you say that "cuán" is universal do you mean most people use it? You won't hear that in most of the hispanoamerican countries. I can tell you that in Colombia the usual form is "qué tan" and nobody will ever say "cuán" not even in writing. Perhaps in poetry. Obviously, if someone uses "cuán" many people will understand (but not all).

Comment: Sigil, Regarding your examples "¿Con qué rapidez vas a caminar?" is correct but "Cómo rápidamente caminas" is not. As @guifa said the correct form would be "¿cuán rápido vas a caminar?" or as we say in southamerica "¿qué tan rápido vas a caminar?" and both are ok. There is also the third form "¿Como de rápido vas a caminar?" but this is not as usual around here.

Comment: @DGaleano I said universal in the sense that it can be found and understood in formal Spanish across the Spanish speaking world. I don't think I've actually heard anyone say it in speech anywhere despite it being the most neutral form :-)

Comment: Ok @guifa I'm waiting for Carlos or fedorqui to comment since I think in Spain they do use "cuán" quite frecuently. I could be wrong :-)

Comment: @DGaleano I shouldn't say I've never heard *cuán*, but I feel pretty confident that a direct question like this wouldn't be used with *cuán*, but it sounds much more natural for me when embedded like in *No tengo ni idea de cuán rápido corre* (probably because *de cómo de* sounds awkward but that's just a guess*)

Comment: @guifa I understand and I agree with you. "de como de" sounds awkward and  "cuán" also sounds weird **to me as a Colombian** because in Colombia everybody will say "No tengo ni idea **de que tan** rápido corre" or "No tengo idea **que tan** rápido iba"

Comment: @DGaleano I hope what I said didn't imply that *cuán* would per se sound natural there — in fact I intended to say the opposite (and moreover my understanding is that *cómo de* sounds outright wrong in Colombia). The general reality, I think, is that the structure —of any variant— is no where near as commonly used as in English. More often than not, the most natural Spanish equivalent will use some other structure entirely, which is probably how *cuán* started dying out (as happened with *cúyo/a(s)*, replaced by *de quién(es)*)

Comment: @guifa - I think you were right the first time when you said adverb.  "Tu tempo es demasiado rápido para este movimiento" -- there, *rápido* is an adjective, but in "Caminé rápido pero no te alcancé" *rápido* is an adverb. // Everything you guys said about "qué tan rápido" fits perfectly for Mexico from my experience.  // What are we going to do about this question?  Close with a link to a duplicate?  Write a new answer?

Comment: @guifa I corrected your first comment to use _adj_ instead of _adv_ and removed its reference in the 2nd comment. Note mods can edit comments anytime, so if you feel it is necessary, just ping us!

Comment: @DGaleano yes, to us _cuán_ is also rather formal and I don't recall hearing anyone using it in a normal conversation. And yes, in Spain we would go for the _cómo de..._ form: _no tengo ni idea de **cómo** de rápido corre_ or even _no tengo ni idea de **lo** rápido que corre_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you probably already reckoned from the comments, there are many alternative ways to express the English meaning of "how adverb do you verb". Which is more "natural" will depend on the local dialect and the register.

In the formal register the "correct" form employs the question word *cuán*, with an adverb following. There are a number of adjectives that, while having a regular adverbial derivation in *-mente*, are often used adverbially in their singular masculine adjectival form. These include *rápido*, *despacio*, *lento*, *fuerte*, etc. So for your example it would be either of the following:

> *¿Cuán rápido vas a caminar?*
>   *¿Cuán rápidamente vas a caminar?*

Other less formal ways employ the phrases *cómo de* and *qué tan*:

> *¿Cómo de rápido vas a caminar?*
>   *¿Qué tan rápido vas a caminar?*

If the adjective is not one of those that can be used adverbially, you will always have to add *-mente*. The rest will be the same.

You may in some cases use a phrase like *con qué [noun]* as you proposed (*¿con qué rapidez...?* etc.) but this sounds distinctively forced in most contexts that I can imagine. It may be the appropriate form in technical speech:

> *¿Con qué velocidad partió el proyectil?*

Finally, your idea:

> *¿Cómo [adverb] [verb]?*

This is **ungrammatical** and you shouldn't use it. It's a straight calque from English *how [adverb]* but Spanish doesn't work like that.